# Air density factor when calculating Airspeed

Tags: avionics, flight-instruments, airspeed, altimeter, pitot-static

I am making my own attitude indicator / AHRS, like a Garmin G5. I am using two pressure sensors to measure altitude & airspeed via  static /pitot lines.

Now I know the formula for calculating airspeed is:   SQRT( (2 * ( Pitot - Static)) / density ) and many sources I find use 1.2 for the density factor, which should actually be 1.225 from my research.

But that density value is for air at sea level.  I'm thinking I should adjust the density factor based on altitude. For instance, at 10k feet, the density drops to about 0.91 kg / m3. Not a big difference but enough to possibly be a factor.

Anyone have experience doing what I am making?

Comment: If IAS is what you're looking for, you should simply not consider the reduction in air density due to altitude. As altitude increases and density decreases, the ASI will show a lower dynamic pressure (IAS) for the same true-airspeed, but the wings and rest of the aircraft will also experience the same reduced dynamic pressure. So use the sea level density irrespective of the altitude - if IAS (dynamic pressure) is what you want your ASI to read. But if you want TAS, you must account for density: $TAS = IAS / √σ$ (where $σ$ is relative density).

Comment: You need to look up and understand the differences between:

True air speed (TAS), 
Indicated air speed (IAS), 
Equivalent air speed (EAS), and
Calibrated air speed (CAS).